# urllib in Python 3 gives me no umlaut

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I try to fetch some google results with BeautifulSoup and urllib:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import quote
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.google.de/search?q=" + quote("ätzend")

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req),"html.parser")

for item in soup.select(".r a"):
        print(item.text)
```

This is the result:

```
�tzende Stoffe � Wikipedia
�tzende Stoffe � Wikipedia
�tzend � Wikipedia
```

I tried using `decode('utf-8')` it doesn't help. What can I do?

Edit:
Also tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8'),"html.parser")
```

Same problem. using utf-16 doesn't help either. The Unicode for the letter `Ä'  is 196 => C4.

Edit2:
Windows Power Shell shows correct results.

Comment: Python can tell you what Unicode code that question mark is. What is it?

Comment: How do I check it in Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord

Comment: Tried hex representation: `�=>0xc4 => should be Ä ....`

Comment: Can you try `item.text.encode().decode('utf-8')`

Comment: encode + decode gives me: `�tzende Stoffe � Wikipedia` ... `ord()` gives me `196` for the first letter Ä

Comment: That is Latin1 encoding.

Comment: Where are you running the code? what ide? I ran it using python command line and I see ätzend.

Comment: Using `"latin1"` gives me an error: `'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x83' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>` ... i am running this in Visual Studio Code on Windows 10. I also tried to directly write the result into an html file. Same result ...

Comment: It works in Power Shell -> without `decode`. Cmd and Git Bash show weird symbols. Writing to a file is still messed up though

Comment: Your code is fine. The problem is the encoding of your terminal. Try using `cp1252` (typical windows encoding). Also: are you 100% sure that the terminal uses a font that can render those characters? Because python can produce whatever result you want but the terminal then has to display it and some fonts simply do not have certain glyphs, and they will show a box or some other weird symbol instead (although the question mark is usually used for invalid characters not "missing glyph" ones).

Comment: Yes you are right. I wrote everything to a file and set Notepad++ to iso-8859-1. Now it works. Question is, how do I convert it to UTF-8 with Python then? When I try this: `print(item.text.decode('iso-8859-1'))` i get this error: `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` ... when I try this: `BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req).read().decode('iso-8859-1'),"html.parser")` i get this error: `'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x84' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: okay, got it...i've set the charset in my html to iso. it works now :) Thank you all!

Comment: @DoubleVoid: Did you make any code change? Please share what you did to see the right output.

Comment: No, I didn't make any changes to my code. I just had to change the file encoding/terminal encoding

Comment: the place where you output result should supports your encoding. If you ever used `sublime` you will know it clearly, because `sublime` always occurs problem same as what you are asking. And there is no way unless you add some plugs to make it support this encoding